# what's the meaning of "&::" in cpp?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, operator-keyword

In cpp, 
I know `&` is used to get the address
and `::` is used to get the member of class,
but, what's the usage of `&::` ?

Here is the example of the function `connect` of qt5:

```
QtWidgetsApplication2::QtWidgetsApplication2(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.pushButton_select, &QPushButton::clicked,this,&::QtWidgetsApplication2::select_file);   
}

void QtWidgetsApplication2::select_file()
{
    file_path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, QStringLiteral("选择文件"), "D:", QStringLiteral("音频文件(*wav)"));
}
```

what's the meaning of `&::` in this line :

> connect(ui.pushButton_select, &QPushButton::clicked,this,**&::QtWidgetsApplication2::select_file**);

why not `&QtWidgetsApplication2::select_file`?

Comment: It's probably a member function pointer that needs to be passed there. Don't see something very `Qt` specific here.

Answer (score 3):

> `::` is used to get the member of class

While this is a correct assumption it is not limited to class only. This operator gives access to a scope. And when it has no identifiers on its left side it explicitly tells the compiler to use the global scope to resolve the given name. If we look at the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) order the *scope resolution* operator `::` is on the top of the list, so it will be resolved first, then the *address of* operator `&`.

So if you would put parentheses, your code should read as

```
& ( (::QtWidgetsApplication2) ::select_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

> what's the meaning of `&::` in this line :

It essentially means that the topmost scope(occuring at the leftmost side) is the **global scope**. That is, we start by looking into the global namespace first.

---

> why not `&QtWidgetsApplication2::select_file`?

This would mean that we start by looking into `QtWidetsApplication2` first instead of the global namespace.

---

Consider the following *contrived example*:

```
namespace P
{
    struct C
    {
        constexpr static int i = 0;
    };
}

struct C
{
    constexpr static int i = 0;
};
//-------------vvv-------->uses global class C
const int *j = &::C::i;
//-------------vv-------->uses class C in namespace P
const int *k = &P::C::i;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1hvnKvYPf)